# British South Asian accent

Tags: british-english, subcontinental-english, accent

This is a two-part question. A lot of British South Asian that are born and bred in the UK have a peculiar accent. It's very different than the familiar Indian accent too. So my question is...

Is there any other way to describe the accent? I found some describe it as ghetto but I'm not sure if it's the right word.

Secondly, what's the origin of the accent and what makes it different? Perhaps few examples with etymology would best explain.

A bit of a context, I'm British South Asian myself and I don't understand why so many speak the way they do. I understand not all speak that way and some even can switch between the two. However I'm unsure if the concept exists in other English speaking country.

Here is an example of the accent. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCk6fSQ21rY

Comment: Young British Asians are changing the way they speak in formal contexts, according to new research: https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2010/dec/16/british-asian-accents-mind-your-language

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a peculiar accent"? Can you expand?

Comment: No offence but you may like to take some help in drafting your questions for simple grammatical errors.

Comment: If I knew exactly what the peculiarity is, I wouldn't be asking the question. I know there is a difference but unsure exactly how. If you don't know what it is either then please leave it to those who does and can answer the question.

Comment: It's an interesting question and I'm not sure the answer will be entirely about *accent* as there is some characteristic in British South Asian speech which is often discernable even when the person's actual accent is a clearly defined British regional one. I've known people whose speech had it and people whose speech didn't and never quite been able to put my finger on it.

Comment: In my experience most British people of Asian descent, born in Britain, adopt the local regional accent of the place where they live. Turban-wearing Sikhs in Birmingham often sound just like Brummies. They may carry vestiges of Asian accent and idiom which they have picked up from their parents, but by and large it seems we learn our accents from our peers. My grandson, born in Manchester, began his speaking career with a Lancashire lilt. But at the age of ten they moved to the Birmingham area, and hearing him now you wouldn't think he had spent a day of his life outside of the Midlands.

Comment: This is a question about British sociolinguistics and should probably be asked on Linguistics SE, where somebody may know something about the current state of sociophonetic research among second- and third-generation S.Asian immigrants. I know that some must be going on, but I know nothing of the details. By the way, to answer the question, the correct way to describe it is phonetically. Giving it fanciful names from other cultures like "ghetto" is not helpful and may be harmful.

Comment: Please consider opening a second question to refer to the second question, since it may be hard to select a single answer concerning both questions. Your second question might be better placed over at [the Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) using the tags "phonology" and "accent".

Comment: I have thought about seperating the questions but for context I believe it is better to be in the same one. An answer can include more than one part.

Comment: The video clip you posted is a spoof of Bradford accent, I'm not sure I would identify it as being South Asian, in the following video you can hear  [local people speak about Bradford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9NfKbgxxv4).

Comment: [The Punjab Road Runners Bradford to Pakistan in Ford Transit](https://youtu.be/DfbemrqGOtw?t=345)

Comment: I know it's a spoof, but it's an accurate one. I agree, there is some part of Bradford accent in there but there is also something else. I'm not really sure what.

Comment: Akbar, I think your link to the comedy sketch is misleading. If there's "something else" in Matt Lucas's accent, don't you think it's more likely to be his *own* accent (Hertfordshire and Bristol) mixed in with his comedic impression of Bradford chavs? It's like relying on Monty Python's *Bruce* sketch as an example of the Aussie accent - in other words, funny but false.

Comment: I welcome you to find me a better example. The "something else" exists in the actually accent and Matt Lucas managed to reproduce it. There may be many other "something else", There will always be slight variation person to person, but that's not what I'm focussing on.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?

Comment: Akbar, I feel this question is too broad to answer. You're asking about a "British South Asian" accent but what it seems you're after is a description of the accent of poorly-educated (the "ghetto" angle) South Asians. No doubt the commonality will be an "Indian" accent, but is there a single word that encompasses all the different English regional accents?

Comment: Regarding possible examples, do the accents in the following clips fit what you're looking for? - Sanjeev in [The Kumars at No. 42](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-0hsywUKdM), or Anpu in [How to speak: British accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAb7l9OWuR8) (starts with a strong "Indian" accent but go to about 2:30 where he drops into a "British" accent and 6:00 for his South London accent).

Answer (score 1):

In the nineteenth century large numbers of teachers were required to teach Received Pronunciation English to Indian Civil servants. Most of these teachers came from Wales. This, I think, is why many Indians, have a 'Welsh Lilt'. Bollywood actors are a good example of this, which may well be the reason why young people have unconsciously adopted it too.

Comment: Welsh teachers over a hundred years ago? The second, third and fourth (?) generation of British Asians (India continent, for US readers) were born in the UK.

Comment: Not my upvote, although the answer is interesting. I wish you could include a reference.